# Example of call stored procedure and get result in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i'm a beginner  in Delphi. I programming with delphi 7.
i have a stored procedure named (ExpertResult) in sqlserver that return a record by a field also get a parameter named (@id) . i want to sent  parameter to sp and get result of this. but i can't do this. i try so much and search so in google but any code cant help me .
one of that codes is :

```
ExpertResult.Parameters.ParamByName('@id').Value := XYZ;  //XYZ as integer
```

help me please .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What kind of variable/object/component is `ExpertResult`, can you show the declaration?

Comment: We would love to help, but we can't if we don't know what type `ExpertResult` is.

Comment: thanks for your attention .the (ExpertResult) get an integer value and return count of some tables as integer

Comment: Reza I would recommend you to read [this tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/databasecourse.htm) about the database programming. Also, I am pretty sure that you shouldn't use the at sign @ when you look for a parameter. Instead try this code: `ExpertResult.Parameters.ParamByName('id').Value := XYZ;`

Comment: I still don't understand what type `ExpertResult` its self is, that's the most important key we need to know. Is it, for example, `TADOQuery`?

Comment: Are you using ADO, Reza? Are you talking to MS SQL Server? You should not ask questions and leave out major facts about your situation.  How would you like if someone asked your help but left most of the facts out?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you do it in Delphi.
Since I don't know how many input and output you have in your stored procedure I show this with one input(string) and one output (boolean). In the Object Inspector you can click the Params and it will show you all inputs and outputs with a number to the left.

```
   ExpertResult.Close; 
   ExpertResult.Params[0] = 'XYZ';
   ExpertResult.Open;  
   MyBoolean := ExpertResult.Params[1];
   ExpertResult.Close;
```